# Content hanging outside closed accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the accordion (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default). There are 3 accordions which open and close on click. Inside each of the 3 accordions are two floated divs. The first 2 accordions look fine, but the third does not. When closed, one of its inside floated divs hangs outside and below the third accordion. When that accordion header is clicked and opens, the floated div pops back up inside the accordion and looks fine. Any one else have this problem? Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Are you [clearing the floats](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) inside each accordion panel?